# Keycloak run with docker compose unable to access https certificate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

When trying to run Keycloak in production mode using docker compose, the following error occurs:

```
keycloak  | 2023-10-30 15:13:12,276 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
keycloak  | 2023-10-30 15:13:12,276 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: /etc/x509/https/tls.key
```

I have followed this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com).

My *docker-compose.yaml*:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_keycloak
    image: postgres:16
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro # turn it on, if you need run init DB
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: kc
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <pass>
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
    networks:
      - keycloak_network

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "--head","fsS", "http://localhost:8080/health/ready" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        KEYCLOAK_VERSION: 22.0.0
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: <pass>
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: kc
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: <pass>
      KC_HOSTNAME: <domain>
      KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH: /auth
      KC_PROXY: passthrough
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /etc/x509/https/tls.key
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    networks:
      - keycloak_network
    command:
      - start --optimized
    volumes:
      - ./certs/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - ./certs/privkey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  keycloak_network:
    driver: bridge
```

As far as I understand this is a file permission problem or the files are not mounted correctly. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bypassed this problem by using nginx as a reversed proxy and setting `KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false`.
https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy

Answer (score 3):

**The issue must be a permission problem.**

So, you have to check the user permission for your certificate or key location. Just try to view the file.

```
# docker exec -it <container_id> cat /etc/x509/https/tls.key
cat: /etc/x509/https/tls.key: Permission denied
```

To execute above command, you have to do following two steps:

1. run the container in start-dev (development mode).
2. with volume which has included tls.key

Now after that, just try this command for Private Key located on Host:

```
chmod -R 644 /etc/privt/certs/tls.key
```

After this, just try above same command to `cat` the key file.

```
# docker exec -it <container_id> cat /etc/x509/https/tls.key

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGLTCCBRWgAwIBAgIRAMvuTcdhvfdlv....
```

Now the permission issue is solved!

Now you can can down the container (using compose file) and change the command from `start-dev` to `start` or `start --optimized` and again up the container (using compose file).

**Now check the logs of Keycloak container and you see there is no error log.**

Comment: thanks for the help! As is said, i bypassed this problem using a reverse proxy, so i won't put in any work to recreate this solution. If anybody does this and can confirm it, i will be happy to accept this answer